# Export excel file from Asp.Net Application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, export-to-excel

I have salary table with some fields and i want retrieve  data from excel format in asp.net.

I use this coding for export excel file format but i didnt get any excel file and errors

so plz guide me what i did wrong

```
    int id=0;
    if (ddlcategory.SelectedValue == "1")
    {
        id = 1;
    }
    else if (ddlcategory.SelectedValue == "2")
    {
        id = 2;
    }
    objinc.Empno = txtfempno.Text;
    objinc.Machno = txttempno.Text;
    objinc.Depart = ddlDepartment.SelectedItem.Text;
    objinc.Emptype = id;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = objdata.sel_Increment(objinc);
    gdvincrement.DataSource = dt;
    gdvincrement.DataBind();
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        string attachment = "attachment;filename=Increment_exc.xls";
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

        StringWriter stw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htextw = new HtmlTextWriter(stw);
        gdvincrement.RenderControl(htextw);
        Response.Write(stw.ToString());
        Response.End();
        Response.Clear();
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "window", "alert('Downloaded Successfully');", true);
```

Comment: Have a look at the [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebapplicationExample) package on [Nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/), it's way easier than trying to do this yourself.

Comment: Have u use NPOI dlls.refer NPOI DLLs

Answer (score 1):

The most usable way to do that which I know is to use excel xml format. It also combines well with MVC pattern (or with just aspx pages as well). So, the first you should do is to prepare view model for your xml file (if you are using MVC pattern). (Same way like you usually do this for html views). Then you should define view that will be excel xml pattern (view for your view model). In that xml pattern you should use your model to pass data in it.

Example:

```
Excel.cshtml

@model MySite.ViewModels.Users.ExcelViewModel
@{
  this.Layout = null;
  this.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
  this.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=users.xls");
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ss:Workbook xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"> 
  <ss:Styles>
    <ss:Style ss:ID="sHeader">
      <ss:Borders>
        <ss:Border ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1" ss:Position="Bottom" />
      </ss:Borders>
      <ss:Font ss:Bold="1"/>
      <ss:Interior ss:Color="#F0F0F0" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
    </ss:Style>
  </ss:Styles>
  <ss:Worksheet ss:Name="Пользователи"> 
    <ss:Table>
      <ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="192"/>
      <ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="192"/>
      <ss:Row>
        @foreach (var item in this.Model.grid.columns)
        {
          <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="sHeader">
            <ss:Data ss:Type="String">@item.name</ss:Data>
          </ss:Cell>
        }
      </ss:Row>
      @foreach (var item in this.Model.items)
      {
        <ss:Row>
          <ss:Cell>
            <ss:Data ss:Type="String">@item.eMail</ss:Data>
          </ss:Cell>
          <ss:Cell>
            <ss:Data ss:Type="String">@item.name</ss:Data>
          </ss:Cell>
        </ss:Row>
      }
    </ss:Table> 
  </ss:Worksheet> 
</ss:Workbook>
```

Then just create usual controller action and return this view from it. That's all.

If you are not familiar with excel xml syntax (like me) you can prepare document with excel and then save it in xml format and use with your application.

If you use web pages instead of mvc you can use similar approach too.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

This is just an Example :

```
 public ActionResult ExportProductManagement(string DownloadToken)
        {
            var productList = _taskProduct.ExportProductManagement(); //= objTask.ExportTroubleCode();
            var result = new StringBuilder();
            result.Append("Part Number|Test Code|Exclude|Material Description|GoAxial Material Description|Division|Distribution Channel|Plant|Material Group 1|Material Group2|Material Group4|Material Group 5|List Price|GoTo Quantity Limit|GoTo Lead Time|Product Hierarchy|Status| DChain Status|ExtractDate \r\n");
            foreach (var item in productList)
            {
                //var itemResult = item.PartNumber + ',' + string.Format("'{0}'", item.TestCode) + ',' + item.MaterialDescription + ',' + item.Division + ',' + item.Plant + ',' + item.MaterialGroup2 + ',' + item.MaterialGroup4 + ',' + item.ExtractDate + ',' + item.IsExcluded + "\r\n";
                var itemResult = string.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}|{3}|{4}|{5}|{6}|{7}|{8}|{9}|{10}|{11}|{12}|{13}|{14}|{15}|{16}|{17}|{18} \r\n", item.PartNumber, item.TestCode, item.IsExcluded, item.MaterialDescription, item.GoAxialParseMaterialDescription != null? item.GoAxialParseMaterialDescription.Trim('#'):null, item.Division, item.DistributionChannel, item.Plant, item.MaterialGroup1, item.MaterialGroup2, item.MaterialGroup4, item.MaterialGroup5, item.ListPrice, item.GoToQuantityLimit, item.GoToLeadTime, item.ProductHierarchy,item.Status ,item.DChainStatus, item.ExtractDate);
                result.Append(itemResult);

            }
            var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(result.ToString());
            var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
            var textName = "Test_ExportFile_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ".xls";
            //use the submitted download token value to set a cookie in the response
            Response.AppendCookie(new HttpCookie("fileDownloadToken", DownloadToken));
            return File(stream, "application/excel", textName);
        }
```